# bgroup does not render properly on ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotmath

The results of `bgroup` from `plotmath` do not seem to render properly as a `ggplot2` annotation. For example ...

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg)) +
  annotate("text", x=2.5, y=25, label="bgroup('(',atop(x,y),')')", parse=TRUE) +
  annotate("text", x=3.5, y=25, label="group('(',atop(x,y),')')", parse=TRUE)
```

... produces the following graph for me ...

[image]

Note how the `bgroup` rendering on the left does not have large parentheses like I would expect (and worked in some previous version of R), whereas the reqular `group` rendering to the right does seem to work.

Am I missing a font? Something else?

I am using R 4.2.2 and ggplot2 3.4.0.

**EDITS**:

1. The code above worked properly in R versions 4.0.5, 4.1.0, 4.1.2, and 4.2.0 (and 3.6.3 according to Jamie in the comments .. but not on Linux according to an answer on R-help).
2. The issue does not seem related to `ggplot2` as the same problem occurs with base graphics.
3. The same issue occurs with R version 4.2.2 whether the code is run in RStudio or the RGui.
4. The same issue occurs (in R version 4.2.2) when the plot is directed to a PNG but not when it is directed to a PDF.

```
plot(0,xlim=c(0,1),ylim=c(0,1))
text(0.5,0.5,expression(bgroup('(',atop(x,y),')')))
```

[image]

Comment: hmm it's working properly for me. I see parenthesis the span the length of x and y on the left hand side. I'm on `R 3.6.3` and `ggplot2 3.3.6`

Comment: I can confirm this behavior. ggplot 3.4.0. Works on R 4.2.0 and 4.2.1, doesn't work on R 4.2.2.

Comment: Did this ever get solved?

Comment: Yes, this was a windows only bug in R v4.2.2. I just checked with R v4.2.3, which was released very recently, and I no longer have this issue.

Answer (score 1):

It's working fine for me on Linux;  I guess you guys are all using Windows?
Note that "rendering" strongly depends on the graphics device.
What is your `.Device` {after plotting}?
I suggest a Windows graphapp font problem, similar to the one just fixed yesterday, also Windows-only:
https://bugs.r-project.org/show_bug.cgi?id=18440

Comment: I am using Windows. `.Device` is "windows" when run in the RGui and "RStudioGD" when run in RStudio.

Answer (score 0):

This bug has been fixed through the following committ [3acfe7a](https://github.com/r-lib/ragg/commit/3acfe7ab04b14a904bd3b067454df6fdf7d76a29) to [{ragg}](https://github.com/r-lib/ragg) on GitHub addressing issue [#132](https://github.com/r-lib/ragg/issues/132) and this posting.